# proper syntax for 'initialize' method and differences from normal method specification

Tags: r, r-s4

The following code illustrates 3 ways of defining 'initialize'.  I have figured out how to make it work (method #1) but I don't understand why the other 2 methods, that look like normal definitions, don't work.  Namely, what's special about the '.Object' variable and why 'signature' is not a function inside 'initialize' (or is it not?)  Could anyone explain the workings of 'initialize' or point to an in-depth explanation?

```
#' foo class definition
foo <- setClass("foo",
                     slots = c(
                       x = 'numeric'
                     )
)

setGeneric( name ="SetPoint", 
    def = function( coord, x, y) { 
        standardGeneric("SetPoint") } ) 

setMethod( f ="SetPoint", signature ="foo", 
def = function( coord, x, y) { print("Setting the point") 
    coord@x = x
    return( coord) } )


#this works
setMethod( f ="initialize", 
signature ="foo", 
def = function(.Object, x = 0.0) { 
    .Object = SetPoint(.Object, x) 
    validObject(.Object) # you must explicitly call the # inspector 
    return(.Object) } )

#this doesn't
setMethod( f ="initialize", 
signature(object = "foo"), 
def = function(.Object, x = 0.0) { 
    .Object = SetPoint(.Object, x) 
    validObject(.Object) # you must explicitly call the # inspector 
    return(.Object) } )

#this doesn't
setMethod( f ="initialize", 
signature = "foo", 
def = function(object, x = 0.0) { 
    object = SetPoint(object, x) 
    validObject(object) # you must explicitly call the # inspector 
    return(object) } )
```

Comment: I think I have an idea, but I still need someone with better R-fu to confirm.  .Object is part of the default setGeneric declaration of 'initialize' as a named argument (see http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/datasets/R/html/methods/html/new.html) and, therefore, is part of the function signature.  As such, it must be named and set in any definition of an 'initialize' method that's compliant with the generic declaration.